# When the password is entered in the login it says that it is not valid but it works offline with no problems in php

Tags: php

When i am using laragon for developement of my website it does work the login normally but when i put on my server raspberry pi online always have a error for the password is incorrect. What could it be?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu7Cb.jpg

All code in this link for the php:

https://pastebin.com/pUQNBjpP

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
  header("location: admin_index.php");
  exit;
}

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'xxxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
define('DB_NAME', 'base_de_dados_museu');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Presumably you didn't set up the database on the pi with the same username and password as the one on your website. We can't see your databases, so you'd have to check that

Answer (score -2):

As this code relies on a MySQL databade running on the same server, the problem most likely related to the database (on the Pi) table not being populated with the correct users.

Comment: This is speculation not a solution. It would be better given as a comment

Comment: (in fairness, this answer was ported from SU, where slightly different standards apply), but its actually more then speculation - I notice that you too did not come up with any other answers - and indeed I discared possibilities like the database not running, or the database schema not set, or msqli plugin not working.  (because of the check  for a failure to connect to the DB).  **What else is left/could it be**?

Comment: I never said you might not be right - in fact I think you probably are, but it's not a definitive answer to the question, that's all...we can't prove it without looking at the servers in question (or getting a data dump of some kind from the OP). The other possibility I suppose is that they changed their code on purpose or by accident and put the wrong credentials in. Those are the only two plausible causes i can think of right now